# Selenium IDE Extraer un valor especifico de una variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo una variable que contiene `32453532`, quiero extraer el primer valor de esa variable, en este caso `'3'`

Uso estos comandos pero no logro obtener el valor `'3'`

```
store text | ruta donde se encuentra el texto |  text

store value |  "${text}"split(" ")[0] | result

echo | ${result}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te propongo que edites tu pregunta e indique que lenguaje estas usando C, C++, Java, Python, Ruby para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola Ricardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor mira el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Añade el resultado actual que estás recibiendo, pero **seguramente el problema sea** el `split` ya que estás separando por `espacio` y no por cadena vacia `""`. Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

store text     | ruta donde se encuentra el texto |  text

execute script | return ${text}.substring(1)      |  result

echo           | ${result}

For selenium IDE